# Why write two () operators

Tags: c++

Why do it twice?
These 2 lines, why do it like this way? Is one enough?

```
inline T& operator() (int row, int col) { return this->m_data[row*NC + col]; }

const inline T& operator() (int row, int col) const { return this->m_data[row*NC + col]; }
```

thank you

```
 *
 * 2-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
 *
 * Simulated by 1-dimension array.
 ******************************************************************************/

#ifndef __2D_ARRAY_H__
#define __2D_ARRAY_H__
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace alg {
    /**
     * 2D Array definition
     */
    template <typename T=char>
        class Array2D {
            private:
                uint32_t NR;        // num of rows
                uint32_t NC;        // num of columns
                T * m_data;         // the place where the array resides.

            public:
                /**
                 * construct an array of size [nrow,col]
                 */
                Array2D(uint32_t nrow, uint32_t ncol) {
                    NR = nrow;
                    NC = ncol;  
                    m_data = new T[nrow*ncol];
                }

                /**
                 * destructor
                 */ 
                ~Array2D() {
                    delete [] m_data;
                }

            private:
                Array2D(const Array2D&);    
                Array2D& operator=(const Array2D&); 

            public:

                /**
                 * return number of rows of this array
                 */
                inline const uint32_t row() const { return NR; }
                /**
                 * return number of columns of this array
                 */
                inline const uint32_t col() const { return NC; }

                /**
                 * return the value by the given (row, col);
                 */
                inline T& operator() (int row, int col) { return this->m_data[row*NC + col]; }
                const inline T& operator() (int row, int col) const { return this->m_data[row*NC + col]; }

                inline T* operator[] (int row) { return &(m_data[row * NC]); }
                inline const T* operator[] (int row) const { return &(m_data[row * NC]); }

                /**
                 * clear the array by a given value
                 */
                void clear(const T & value) {
                    for(uint32_t i=0; i<NR*NC;i++){
                        m_data[i] = value;
                    }
                }
        };
}

#endif //
```

Comment: Note that names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__2D_ARRAY_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: @Pete Becker really, can you please how me reference?

Comment: 17.6.4.3.2 [global.names] /1: "... Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use...."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One is `const` and the other is not.

The difference is that when you have a `const` reference to a `Array2D` you're only allowed to call member functions marked `const`. In this case that means the 2nd version, where it must necessarily return a `const` reference to the element it holds.

If you have a non-`const` reference, though, that 2nd version means you can't use `operator()` to make any changes to your `Array2D`.

If you look at standard library containers like `std::vector` you'll see that they do the same thing. You can get an `iterator` from `begin()` and a `const_iterator` from `begin() const`.

Comment: Maybe one could say that the const version is a getter and the non-const is a setter?

Comment: @user2672165 no, they're both getters. One gives a const refence while the other a regular one.

Comment: ... but of course, the non-const version can be used to modify the contents of the array. So in that way, it works similarly to a setter.

Comment: @Adam: Of course. But why would you use a non-const version if you don't want to change the value?

Comment: @user2672165 If you have a choice, then it's up to you. All I'm saying is that they both *get* a reference to an element.

Answer (score 2):

The first, non-constant version returns a reference that can be modified. If you have a constant object, you still want to be able to at least read the value, so you have to provide a second constant version.

Answer (score 2):

The two () operators are not the same.  `inline T& operator() (int row, int col);`  returns a reference that allows the returned value to be modified. `const inline T& operator() (int row, int col) const` returns a reference that disallows the returned value from being modified.  Also if the calling object is a `const alg::Array2D&`, than it can ONLY use the `const operator();`.  So in order to allow users of the Array2D class to properly use const objects.  It is best practice to implement both signatures for the operator ().

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function `void make_something (const Array2D<char> &input, Array2D<char> &output)`. This function lets input untouched, makes some operation with it, and writes the result to output. Reading from input would only be possible if there is also a const operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline T& operator() (int row, int col) { return this->m_data[row*NC + col]; }
```

returns a non-const reference to the data in `m_data[row * NC + col]`, which means I can do

```
auto& ref = obj(x, y);
ref = BAD_DATA;
```

and your object can't stop me. The `const` variant protects against this, and can be fingerprinted as const because it has no side effects on the object as a result.

```
inline const T& operator() (int row, int col) const { return this->m_data[row*NC + col]; }
```

This allows me to propagate constness outwards:

```
void myFunc(const Object& obj) /* I'm only going to look */
{
    const auto& ref = obj(x, y);
    std::cout << x << ',' << y << " = " << ref << '\n';
}
```